# Do we have any plugin or setting to have a good UI inspector for Rhodes App

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I'm really bored with `RhoSimulator` inspect, as its not user friendly and we can't event perfectly inspect the design.

Even we can't right click on that to have the options to go back or go home or inspect. I had seen this on the previous version. But its not available now.

For a single minor UI issue it takes huge time using the inspect. Anybody have any idea how can we make this better.

Comment: What version of the RhoMobile suite are you using and on what OS? The RhoSimulator inspector is based around the webkit inspector and is usually quite good. If there's an issue on the new v4.x you can open a ticket on [github](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhoelements-issues/issues?state=open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set the local port to a static one, and run the app on the browser. So you can have huge number of inspector for you help.

If you see, on your `rhoconfig.xml` file, you will found,

```
#local_server_port = 8080
```

Just un-comment it, and set to some port, lets say 8081 **// if no one is using this port**

```
local_server_port = 8081
```

Now on the browser, go for `http://127.0.0.1:8081/app/`, you can see the app running on the browser. That's it.

Comment: Nice. This would surely save my precious time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just remember to comment this option when you deploy your app, as only one app can bind a tcp/ip port as a server. If you have two apps using the same port, the second one you launch will be stuck. And I think that in this way you loose the capability to test the webview.execute_js API.